# AutoMapper - AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, identity

I'm having this exception when I'm trying to map from one object to another.

On my global.asax.cs I got this:

```
RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new AppContext()));
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<AppUser, TokenAuthorizationModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UserName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Role, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => roleManager.FindById(src.Roles.First().RoleId).Name));
        });
```

And I got this AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException exception on my login controller, especifically on this line:

```
TokenAuthorizationModel tokenClaims = Mapper.Map<TokenAuthorizationModel>(validUser);
```

And these are my models:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual List<CourseModel> Courses { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int Reputation { get; set; }
}
```

And destination:

```
public class TokenAuthorizationModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Can anybody give me hand? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is roleManager making a call to the database? If so, i'd definitely avoid doing something like that inside automapper.

Comment: But I need to, what other way would you do it? Because I need to get the role of the user which is in the database.

Comment: `Users` HAVE `Roles` right? So if you need roles here, the roles should be eagerly loaded when looking up the user.

Comment: I get that. The thing is, in Identity the roles on Users are given by id. Then, you get the name of the role by its respective id (this is where you need to call to the database).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is at this part:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Role, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => roleManager.FindById(src.Roles.First().RoleId).Name));
```

I would not use `MapFrom` in this case. Try to use `ResolveUsing` method instead which takes a lambda function.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Role, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => roleManager.FindById(src.Roles.First().RoleId).Name));
```

If this does not work please let me know!

Comment: I just tried that. And it didn't work. :( It keeps throwing the same exception.

Comment: Can u please share the full exception here

Comment: Sure, it says: "An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code".

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess you meant this: +  $exception {"Error mapping types.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nAppUser -> TokenAuthorizationModel\r\nRolagroup.Models.AppUser -> Rolagroup.Models.TokenAuthorizationModel\r\n\r\nType Map configuration:\r\nAppUser -> TokenAuthorizationModel\r\nRolagroup.Models.AppUser -> Rolagroup.Models.TokenAuthorizationModel\r\n\r\nProperty:\r\nRole"} AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException

Comment: can you debug if this `roleManager.FindById(src.Roles.First().RoleId).Name` returns a value ?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a resolver for the Role property and use dependency injection inside it so you have the right DbContext as you would anywhere else in your app.